# json.dump a concurrent.futures.Future()?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, future

Let's say I have some futures:

```
f = concurrent.futures.Future()
data = [f]
```

And eventually I want to dump these in JSON, and I guarantee that futures were resolved by that time:

```
f.set_result(42)
json.dumps(data)
```

How can I marry the two?

Comment: I have a hack that overrides `jsonEncoder` class, but is there perhaps a better solution?

Answer (score 4):

Overriding the JSONEncoder class and calling `o.result()` on Future instances is one way.

```
class CustomJSONEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, o, *args, **kwargs):
        if isinstance(o, concurrent.futures.Future):
            return o.result()
        return super(CustomJSONEncoder, self).default(o, *args, **kwargs)

json.dumps(data, cls=CustomJSONEncoder)
```

To make it work without a custom JSONEncoder, you could iterate through the data structure yourself, calling `o.result()`:

```
data = [o.result() if isinstance(o, concurrent.futures.Future) else o for o in data]
```

Or modify `data` in place:

```
for i, o in enumerate(data):
    if isinstance(o, concurrent.futures.Future):
        data[i] = o.result()
```

Comment: I think you are making an assumption on representation of result in `return o.result` -- doesn't that need to be piped through `super().default()` too? In fact, perhaps it's best to recursively call `return self.default(o.result)`just in case `result` is a container that has another resolved future in it?

Comment: You only call `super().default()` to raise a `TypeError`:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.JSONEncoder.default

Comment: If `o.result()` is an iteratable and you return it, it should still get serialized properly. I checked the Python source to make sure, anything returned by `default()` undergoes the regular serialization process.

Answer (score 0):

```
json.dumps([d.result() for d in data])
```

Comment: Great, but that assumes data model knowledge at the call site. I'd rather have something generic.

Comment: Create a JSON-aware subclass of Future? Probably only needs to override __str__ to call `self.result()`?